# Why color is not getting applied in CSS/SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Color gets applied when using `:visited` pseudo class.

```html
<a href="#" class="footer__link">Company</a>
```

```scss
.footer {
   &__link {
        &:link,
        /*&:visited*/ {
            color: yellow ;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the closing brace for the &__link selector.

Comment: The missing brace is the problem. The code works now: https://jsfiddle.net/njpocb1a/ If you only want it yellow on visited then uncomment the rule and remove &:link

Comment: @Brandon I really don't understand but for some reaasons it was not working for me in Chrome but now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to nest it or make it any complicated.
I think this should work for you.

```
.footer__link:visited {
  color: yellow;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your nesting is completely fine,
i copied your code and run it in codepen and it worked properly , there are just 2 possibility about the issue

1. maybe you need to delete that "`,`" after the `&:link` which is unlikely the issue to be about this part but test it.
2. your commenting , because in SASS when you comment out something with "`//`" , the whole line becomes comment and then the first curly bracket becomes as a part of comment and then you declaration fails due to lack of first "`{`"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra code, Just copy and paste the below code and it will work just fine.

```
.footer {
      /* FOOTER STYLING */

      &__link {
         color: yellow;

         /* LINK STYLING */
      }
 }
```